# Paginado de tabla con ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, laravel-5

estoy usando laravel 5.4. En mi tabla traigo los formulario que completaron los usuarios. Se ve de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso un select, para poder traer en un json y completar la tabla
select:

```
   <select  id="myselect" class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-size="4" data-live-search="true" name="taskOption" title="Buscar">
       <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
                <option data-subtext="{{$user->email}}" value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </select>
```

tabla:

```
<div class="panel-body no-padding table-responsive">
    <table  class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Nombre y apellido</th>
           <th>Dni</th>
           <th>Edificio</th>
           <th>Torre</th>
           <th>Piso/Dep</th>
           <th>Cant</th>
           <th>Fecha</th>
           <th>Inquilino?</th>
           <th>Fin contrato</th>
           <th>Observación</th>
           <th>L g</th>
           <th>Pago</th>
           <th>Entrega</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tabla">

      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

el json que me devuelve es el siguiente

```
[{"nombre":["Martina","sdasd"],"apellido":["Gonzalez","sadsada"],"dni":[4200090,123],"edificio":["gama","dasda"],"torre":["hola","3"],"departamento":["C","C"],"cantidad":[2,1],"fecha":["2017-08-28","2017-08-28"],"llavero":[1,0],"estado":[0,0],"estadoentregado":[0,0],"piso":["J","2"],"dueno":["no","no"],"contrato":["-","-"],"descripcion":["hola","-"],"id":[17,18]}]
```

el script que uso para completar la tabla es:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#myselect').change(function(){
      var seleccionado = $(this).find(':selected').val();
      $.ajax({
              type:'get',
              url:'/buscar/'+seleccionado+'/',
              dataType: 'json',
              data:'/buscar/'+seleccionado+'/',
              success: function (response) {
                $('#tabla tr').remove();
                var trHTML = '<tr>';
                for (var i = 0; i < response[0].nombre.length; i++) {
                  if(response[0].estado[i]==0){h=`<a href="/actualizarpago/${response[0].id[i]}"><i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times"></i>`;}
                  else{h = `<a href="/actualizarpago/${response[0].id[i]}"><i style="color:green" class="fa fa-check"></i></a>`}
                  if(response[0].estadoentregado[i]==0){ p=`<a href="/actualizar/${response[0].id[i]}"><i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times"></i></a>`;}
                  else{p = '<i style="color:green" class="fa fa-check"></i>'}
                  if(response[0].llavero[i]==0){l='<i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times"></i>';}
                  else{l = '<i style="color:green" class="fa fa-check"></i>'}
                  var lg = '<td id="fila'+[i]+'" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);">'+ l + '</td><td>';
                  trHTML += '<td>' + response[0].nombre[i]+' '+ response[0].apellido[i] +'</td><td>'
                  + response[0].dni[i] + '</td><td>'
                  + response[0].edificio[i] + '</td><td>'
                  + response[0].torre[i] + '</td><td>'
                  + response[0].piso[i]+' / '+ response[0].departamento[i] + '</td><td>'
                  + response[0].cantidad[i] + '</td><td>'
                  + response[0].fecha[i] + '</td><td>'
                  + response[0].dueno[i] + '</td><td>'
                  + response[0].contrato[i] + '</td><td>'
                  + response[0].descripcion[i] + '</td>'+lg
                  + h + '</td><td>'
                  + p + '</td><tr>';
                }
                trHTML += '</tr>';
                 $('#tabla').append(trHTML);
              },
            });
          });
  });
  </script>
```

Mi problema es que no se como paginar los datos en la tabla que vienen en el json. 
Ademas en la tabla tiene dos columnas "Pago" y "Entregado" la cual podes hacer click para poder cambiarlo de estado (actulamente tenes que hacer click una por una para cambiarle el estado), quiero agregarle la funcionalidad que pueda seleccionar varias.

Comment: ¿Ya tienes la paginación en el controlador de Laravel?

Comment: Porque usas <?php codigo :?> si estas usando laravel, usa directivas de Blade @foreach($users as $user)

Comment: Como opciones tenes, o usar la paginación de Laravel o la que yo uso para ajax es usar Datatables y te pagina y agrega filtros solos!